# Unable to launch * because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode-project

Ok.. This has me pulling my hair out. I have searched the previously posted questions and answers and none of them seem to work. I fear i'm at the frantic stage and hope i'm not missing anything so here goes... I am trying to simple run an app im working on on my device. However I am presented with the error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.me.runningTracker because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

```
iOS: 16.5.1
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
```

Here's the exact steps i've taken:

1. I created an icloud account today. I then created a developer account(free). Then I downloaded Xcode.
2. in xcode I went to settings, account and then added my new account using the new icloud email.
3. I then tried to run the app. I got an error about not verified.
4. I went to VPN & Device management, I clicked the Developer App and clicked the "Trust" button.
5. I then clicked "Verify App" - a little spinner loads in the top right. But then nothing.

How do I get the app verified so I can run it on my device?